# bash script with array works on linux not on mac os x

Tags: bash

Here is a simple script, distilled from something actually useful, that works on fedora but not on OS X Lion.

```
declare -a directory_contents=($(ls .))
test -e ${directory_contents[0]}
echo $?
```

On linux it returns 0, i.e., test -e passes. On Mac, it returns 1.

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: The code above returns 0 on my OS X 10.6.8 ...

Comment: @NickAtoms, [yes](https://gist.github.com/2401956). It's good old bash  3.2.48(1)-release.

Comment: Apple still distributes bash 3.2, rather than a bash 4.x.  Is that the source of your trouble?

Comment: Returns 0 for me on OS X 10.7.3 (bash 3.2.48(1)-release) unless the first filename has a space -- I think @Nick Atoms nailed it.

Comment: pduey, can you show us the list of filenames?  What IS the value of `${directory_contents[0]}` ?

Comment: @Graham, I tried it in many directories, always same. I figured it out after looking away for a while. I'll answer below so nobody else wastes time like I did. And I know I've done this before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I neglected to clarify in my original question is that my "script" is really a bash function. The cause of my issue is that "ls" is resolving to an alias with "--color=auto", adding unprintable characters to the actual filename.

Always define variables to hold the full path to the executables used in a script, e.g., "LS=/bin/ls". And, per answers above, ls might not be you best choice for a robust production script.

Answer (score 4):

If the first file returned by `ls` has spaces in the name, `${directory_contents[0]}` will not expand to the full file name (only up to the first space).  Does this condition apply to your OSX test and not your Fedora test?

Adding the following line before the declare statement might fix the problem:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

reference: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-passing-arrays-with-spaces-611159/

Answer (score 2):

Nick's answer is correct.  But you should also remember that except in highly controlled environments, `ls` is *not* something you should use to populate variables with filenames.  There are a number of other ways to pick a single filename.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ls -l foo*
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Apr 16 21:01 foo bar.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  wheel  0 Apr 16 21:01 foo.txt
[ghoti@pc ~]$ test1=`for i in foo*txt;do echo $i; break; done`
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $test1
foo bar.txt
[ghoti@pc ~]$ test2=`find . -name foo\*.txt -print | head -1`
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo $test2
./foo.txt
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Obviously, not all methods will return files in the same order.

Also be mindful of filenames that begin with a hyphen.  :-)

Comment: Upvote since your answer gets to the heart of the matter, i.e., don't rely on "ls". Although it's not the actual cause. I'm answering my own question, even though now it seems obvious, so it hopefully helps someone else.